# Accessing properties with has_many :though

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, has-many-through

In the below code I have two models that are associated via `has_many :through`. The `Component` model also `belongs_to Category` model. I'm trying to access the `Category.title` property from a `Collection` though a `Component` so something like: `@collection.components[:id].category.title`

In the below code ":components" puts:

```
[#<Component id: 23, name: "l-shaped-desks", title: "L-Shaped Desks", category_id: 10, created_at: "2013-04-07 00:18:07", updated_at: "2013-04-07 00:18:07">, #<Component id: 25, name: "writing-tables", title: "Writing Tables", category_id: 10, created_at: "2013-04-07 00:18:29", updated_at: "2013-04-07 00:18:29">]
```

Where each `"#<Component>"` is one that is checked form the generated check boxes.

The problem is I can't figure out how to access that information. I've tried `:components[0].category.title` but get the error:

```
undefined method `category' for :components:Symbol
```

**_form.html.haml**

```
= form_for @collection do |f|
  - if @collection.errors.any?
    #error_explanation
      %h1= "#{pluralize(@collection.errors.count, "error")} prohibited this collection from being saved:"
      %ul
        - @collection.errors.full_messages.each do |msg|
          %li= msg

  - Category.products.each_slice(2) do |column|
    .column
      - column.each do |category|
        .column-group
          %h1 
            = category.title
          - category.components.each do |component|
            .checkbox
              = check_box_tag "component#{component.id}", component.id, @collection.components.include?(component), :name => 'collection[component_ids][]'
              = label_tag "component#{component.id}", component.title

  .field
    = f.label :title
    = f.text_field :title
  .field
    = f.label :components
    = f.text_field :components //This will fill a text_input with [#<Component...
    / = f.text_field :components[0].category.title //This does not work
  .actions
    = f.submit 'Save'
```

**category.rb**

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  default_scope order('id ASC')

  CATEGORY_KINDS = [["Product", 0],["Page", 1]]

  scope :products, where(:kind => 0)
  scope :pages, where(:kind => 1)

  attr_accessible   :name, 
                    :title, 
                    :kind,
                    :section, 
                    :component

  has_many          :sections
  has_many          :components

  before_save       :create_name

  private

  def create_name
    self.name = title.parameterize
  end
end
```

**component.rb**

```
class Component < ActiveRecord::Base
  default_scope order('components.id ASC')

  attr_accessible         :category_id, 
                          :name, 
                          :title,
                          :collection_ids,
                          :style_ids

  has_many                :collection_components, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many                :collections,   :through => :collection_components

  has_many                :component_styles
  has_many                :styles,        :through => :component_styles

  belongs_to              :category

  validates_presence_of   :category
  validates_presence_of   :title

  before_save             :create_name

  private

  def create_name
    self.name = title.parameterize
  end
end
```

**collection.rb**

```
class Collection < ActiveRecord::Base
  default_scope order('collections.id ASC')

  attr_accessible               :style_id, 
                                :name, 
                                :title,
                                :component_ids


  has_many                      :collection_components, :include => :component
  has_many                      :components,            :through => :collection_components
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :collection_components, :allow_destroy => true

  belongs_to                    :style

  validates_presence_of         :style
  validates_presence_of         :title
  validates_presence_of         :component_ids

  before_save                   :create_name

  private

  def create_name
    self.name = title.parameterize
  end
end
```

**collection_component.rb**

```
class CollectionComponent < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :collection_id, 
                  :component_id

  belongs_to      :collection
  belongs_to      :component
end
```

Comment: Where are you trying to reference the `title`? In the form view you showed?

Comment: Sorry about that. I added some comments in the _form near the bottom. Let me know if it requires further clarification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're trying to edit a property of a related model, you can typically use a nested `fields_for` for the associated model. See the documentation for `fields_for` in the [Rails Form Helpers guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html) for details.

But if you're mainly just interested in the correct way to reference the `title` attribute of the associated Category instance, this should work (for accessing the Category of the *first* Component):

```
@collection.components.first.category.title
```

(Note that I've replaced `[0]` with `first`, but they're effectively the same.)

Comment: I'll give that a try thanks. However, I'd also like to access `Category.title` from `Collection` via `Component` in other areas of the app as well. For instance, in the index.html.haml for `Collections` I'd like to be able to so display which `Categories` a `Collection` belongs to relative to it's `Components`.  I suppose the larger question is, what is the proper syntax to access information in the `#<component>` element.

Comment: So then for subsequent `Components` is it "second", "third",..."twentyfifth",..."onehundredeighythird"?

Comment: No, that style is just used if you're hard-coding to use the first element always. If you need to fetch an index offset, continue using `[0]`, `[1]`, etc.

Comment: Or loop with a variable, obviously. E.g., `@collection.components.each { |component| component.category.title  # do something with that value }`

Comment: Yeah, it seems to be working with normal array notation now. I'm not sure why I was having so many problems before. Thanks for following though!

Comment: One odd thing I did notice was that in `index.html.haml` this works: `collection.components[0].category.title` however in the `form_for` tag `= f.text_field :components[0].category.title` throws an error of `undefined method `category' for "c":String`

Comment: The expression `:components[0]` returns a String `c` (character at index 0 of the Symbol `:components`). But String class doesn't have a `category` method, which is why you get that error. Basically, that kind of expression won't ever work. You need to call methods on model objects, not on Symbols (like `:components`)